# How do I customize the ID attributes of login and registration forms?

Tags: django

I have two classes in  `forms.py`:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
 '''
 Form to log in a user
 '''
 error_messages= {
 "invalid_login": _("Incorrect %(username)s/password combo")
 }
 username= forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Email"}))
 password= forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Password"}))

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
 '''
 Form that makes user using just email as username
 '''
 error_messages= {
  "password_mismatch": _("Passwords do not match."),
  "duplicate_email": _("Email already exists."),
  "unique": _("Email already exists"),
 }
 username= forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Email"}))
 password1= forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Password"}))
 password2= forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"), widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Confirm password"}))

 class Meta:
  model= User
  fields= ("username",)
```

I load them both on `login_register.html`, as is shown in this view:

```
def login_register(request, template="pages/login_register.html"):
 registration_form= RegisterForm()
 login_form= LoginForm()
 return render(request, template, {"registration_form": registration_form, "login_form": login_form})
```

But when they both load on the page, this causes the page to have two `input` tags, both with the `id` attribute `id_username`. How do I change the `id` attributes of my forms' `input` tags?

Comment: Just change the variable name.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `id` attribute to one of the fileds:

```
username= forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Email", "id": "id_login_username"}))
```